# Grails 3.3: Rending Plugin 2.0.3: UnknownTemplateException Could not find template for 'template' on production

Tags: grails, groovy, tomcat8, gsp

I am attempting to generate a PDF in Grails using the [grails rending plugin](https://github.com/gpc/rendering).

The following will work when running `gradle bootRun`

```
class DocumentService {

   def generatePdf() {

     // ...

       ByteArrayOutputStream stream = pdfRenderingService.render(
            template    : 'template_name',
            model       : [ name : 'taylor' ],
            controller  : 'controllerName'
       )

   }
}
```

However, when deployed on tomcat8.

```
 grails.plugins.rendering.document.UnknownTemplateException: Could not find template for 'template_name'
at grails.plugins.rendering.document.XhtmlDocumentService.createTemplate(XhtmlDocumentService.groovy:102)
at grails.plugins.rendering.document.XhtmlDocumentService$_generateXhtml_closure1.doCall(XhtmlDocumentService.groovy:66)
at grails.plugins.rendering.document.RenderEnvironment.with(RenderEnvironment.groovy:70)
at grails.plugins.rendering.document.RenderEnvironment.with(RenderEnvironment.groovy:60)
at grails.plugins.rendering.document.XhtmlDocumentService.generateXhtml(XhtmlDocumentService.groovy:65)
at grails.plugins.rendering.document.XhtmlDocumentService.createDocument(XhtmlDocumentService.groovy:35)
at grails.plugins.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:36)
at grails.plugins.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:35)
```

Comment: Have you tried camel case notation for naming templates? e.g. `templateName`. Check also the actual code of this class: https://github.com/gpc/rendering/blob/master/grails-app/services/grails/plugins/rendering/document/XhtmlDocumentService.groovy

Comment: Thank you @Michal_Szulc for your response, changing the template name to camel case did not work. I have been though the source code and followed the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a gsp as a template file.
You need to include: grails-gsp plugin in your build.gradle

apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"